# No Internet connection with ethernet

Tags: networking, ethernet, connection

my ethernet cable connection have problems with the internet on Ubuntu 14.10 (Also on 14.04).
If i fill in Network Settings manually he shows that he is connected but i cant reach the router or websites.
If I use the DHCP he gets no connection and is always connecting.
If i use the sudo dhclient eth0 it does work and work he shows no result.

What could I do?

Comment: It's really hard to tell what's wrong based on this information. It could be everything, from configuration to software to hardware problems, or possibly problems with the network itself. Give us some context so we know where to start. Did it ever work before? If yes, what did you do between the moment where it worked and where it didn't? Does it work under other systems you may have installed, e.g., Windows? Are you sure your network ought to work properly? Do you have other devices in the same network that work fine? etc.

Comment: Sounds like the dhclient doesn't start on your Ubuntu machine.  But you could have done our work much easier and better if you told us a bit more how you set up the network.  If you using `NetworkManager` or wrote in `/etc/network/interfaces`.  And if so, what are the contents? Have you tried wireshark?

Answer (score 0):

A wild guess, but I had the same behavior when the dhcp of my router wasn't working. Do you have another computer you can try it on?